# Should we tag the airplane model in [aircraft-identification] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the past few days there has been an ongoing wave of edits which adds the aircraft model to some old questions. Some of these edits add the aircraft model tag to a question asking to identify the aircraft model.

Is this a good idea? For one I think the tag should not be there, because the tags should reflect the question asked by the OP. Obviously if the OP can tag the proper aircraft model then the question would not have been asked, so these tags are "back filled" later when someone answers the question. However tagging the question is probably helpful for locating related questions.

I just wonder what is the community's opinion here?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/do-we-need-a-tag-for-each-airplane-model-we-mention?cb=1

Comment: @tim not strictly, this is about questions already tagged with "aircraft-identification".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I would not add them, the question is about identification, not about the model, i.e. it does not directly ask for some specifics or some details of the model, even if it could be argued that it indirectly does.

Comment: The question is about identifying the model so how can the question not be about the model?

Answer (score 5):

I think it should be added so that it can be of greater use to future visitors to the site.

These questions are about a specific aircraft, even if the model is not known at the time of asking, therefore they should be tagged accordingly.

Also, tags make it easier to find questions related to your topic/aircraft. Why would you want to make it harder to find questions?