# Should we have tags for specific aircraft engines?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, we have tags for specific models of aircraft (for instance, [boeing-737](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-737), [de-havilland-comet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/de-havilland-comet), [tu-154](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tu-154), [bombardier-crj](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bombardier-crj)), which makes sense, given the large numbers of questions regarding specific aircraft.  Specific manufacturers also sometimes have their own tags, such as [boeing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing), [airbus](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus), or [lockheed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lockheed).

We do *not*, however, currently have tags for specific models of aircraft *engines*, even though we have many questions regarding specific engines.

Examples:

- GE90: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/67017/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/52275/22726), [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23769/22726), [4](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/31544/22726), [5](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35046/22726), [6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33579/22726)
- GEnx: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49589/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/20943/22726)
- CFM56: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/59751/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34568/22726), [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33967/22726), [4](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34585/22726), [5](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49989/22726), [6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54419/22726), [7](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/70734/22726), [8](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46667/22726), [9](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36743/22726)
- CF6: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37135/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50891/22726), [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/51747/22726), [4](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46667/22726), [5](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35046/22726), [6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/66673/22726)
- JT8D: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24351/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/67711/22726), [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/70316/22726)
- JT3D: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9432/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/67711/22726)
- PT6: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54784/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22151/22726), [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11906/22726), [4](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48763/22726), [5](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/71414/22726)
- Trent 900: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26937/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45423/22726), [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45765/22726), [4](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48424/22726), [5](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48744/22726), [6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48544/22726), [7](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48547/22726), [8](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45628/22726)
- Trent 1000: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13178/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53134/22726), [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47727/22726)
- Trent XWB: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48012/22726), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35000/22726), [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17253/22726)

Currently, questions about specific engines have to use the [engine-design](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine-design) (and/or, sometimes, [aircraft-design](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-design)) tags, along with the tag for the general category of engine (e.g., [jet-engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jet-engine), [turbojet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turbojet), [turbofan](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turbofan), [turboprop](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turboprop), [piston-engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piston-engine), [rocket](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocket), [pulsejet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pulsejet), etc.), and, sometimes, the tag for one or more of the aircraft types using the engine; if the engines had their own tags, it would eliminate the need for all this beating about the bush.

Should specific engines have their own tags, like specific aircraft and specific manufacturers?

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, **no.**

Those are 11 engine models, amounting to 55 questions out of 17,000 questions, in 6 years.

I don't think the very, very small volume warrants the effort and related maintenance. The specificity is not regular.

I'm aware the same can be argued for most aircraft-model tags ([Do we need a tag for each airplane model we mention?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3423/14897)).

Note that a tag is meant to be [a topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

Is it really a topic when a tag has only a few questions? (A question that I might bring up soon, just food for thought for now. Possible it's been asked and answered on MSE.)

My argument in other words, what does one gain by browsing a tag with single-digit questions or filtering the home page to wait months for a very rare question to be highlighted? Searching for "CFM56 is:q" for example works well for this specificity IMO.