# Merge [boeing-747-8] → [boeing-747]?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I don't know why the -8i/f variants get special treatment, since the same is not done for the variants of the 737, 777, etc.

Unless I've missed something, I request a tag merge for [boeing-747-8](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-747-8) x27 → [boeing-747](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-747) x99.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was discussed that we do not need variant-specific tags of aircraft models [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/do-we-need-a-tag-for-each-airplane-model-we-mention). Unless there is a change in consensus, I support the tag merge.